# using template parameters in function arguments does not work gcc4.8

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, lambda

I have a function like this  :

```
template<typename Iterator>
void sort2(Iterator it,
           std::function<bool(typename std::remove_pointer<
                              typename  Iterator::iterator_type>::type,
                                          int)> func)
{
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    sort2(a.begin(),[](int,int){return false;});
}
'main()::__lambda0' is not derived from 'std::function<bool(typename std::remove_pointer<typename Iterator::iterator_type>::type, int)>'
 sort2(a.begin(),[](int,int){return false;});
                                           ^
```

When I  change it to  :

```
template<typename Iterator>
void sort2(Iterator it,
           std::function<bool(typename std::remove_pointer<
                              typename  vector<int>::iterator/*I change this*/::iterator_type>::type,
                                          int)> func)
{
}
```

It compiles fine ...

What is wrong with the first function ?!

It seems correct ... why does it give compile errors ?

Comment: `iterator::iterator_type` will be a tag type (in this case, std::random_access). You probably just want `Iterator::reference`

Comment: Though I would point out that I would just template the second argument so that function pointers and operator structs could be used as well.

Comment: Note: passing a single iterator instead of a range will not work (although, it is an example)

Comment: Your code compiles on gcc-4.9 and clang-3.4

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I tried std::refrence too ... It doesn't work either . https://ideone.com/169L0c

Comment: @Praetorian It does not compile on gcc 4.8 ... It seems to work on vs2013 too ! Is it a gcc bug ?!

Comment: @MadScienceDreams `Iterator::iterator_type` won't be anything - you're thinking of `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::iterator_category`.

Comment: @omid not std::reference, Iterator::reference (as to not pass by value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterators have no member named `iterator_type`. You want `Iterator::value_type` ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6d3fcaf7301e229)):

```
template<typename Iterator>
void sort2(Iterator it,
           std::function<bool(typename std::remove_pointer<
                              typename Iterator::value_type>::type,
                                          int)> func)
{
}
```

or better yet, use `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type` so your function will accept pointers as well as class type iterators ([Coliru again](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/514455b1ff7a3cbb)):

```
template<typename Iterator>
void sort2(Iterator it,
           std::function<bool(typename std::remove_pointer<
                              typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>::type,
                                          int)> func)
{
}
```

A more generic version would accept the comparator type as a template parameter and use SFINAE to constrain that type to functions callable with two `value_type`s having a return type convertible to bool instead of using convertibility to `std::function<bool(value_type, value_type)`:

```
template <typename Iterator>
using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

template<typename Iterator, typename Function>
auto sort2(Iterator first, Iterator last, Function func) ->
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_convertible<decltype(func(std::declval<ValueType<Iterator>>(),
                                      std::declval<ValueType<Iterator>>())),
                        bool>::value
  >::type
{
    std::sort(first, last, func);
}
```

It's hideously ugly - constraining with SFINAE always is - [but at least gcc compiles it successfully](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce8d7ce89fb3bf5d).

Comment: gcc still doesn't compile it. And `iterator_type` looked strange to me too, but I found some MSDN doc that talked about it.

Comment: @omid gcc compiles it [if you force the second argument to be in a non-deduced context](https://ideone.com/VNebIX). So I suppose the question here is which compiler is wrong.